# Manage configuration per environment

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, app-config

How can I instruct app.config to use different reference per environment?

For example: I have a configuration folder that contains 3 folders - Dev, QA and Prod
- Configuration
    - Dev
        * AppSettings.config
    - QA
        * AppSettings.config
    - Prod
        * AppSettings.config

My app.config have this reference

```
<appSettings configSource="Configuration\Dev\AppSettings.config" />
```

I would like to have something like

```
<appSettings configSource="Configuration\[$ENV]\AppSettings.config" />
```

$ENV config should be defined in appSettings or  if not possible other external source.

Also what is the best practice to manage that? (without using fancy Chef server or configuration server).

**I'm also trying to avoid post script manipulation.**

Comment: what about `config transform` (source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx)? Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @kienct89 I've added another case that is more similar to my real case. This way I can't resolve it with debug release...

Comment: debug/release are just two **default** configurations that .NET automatically creates. You can add as many configuration options as you want to by go to `Configuration Manager` \ `Active solution configuration` \ `New`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use XML configuration file trasforms (see [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Since default configuration transforms are implemented for `Web.config`, you need to use a Visual Studio extension to get this feature to any configuration file. [Slow Cheetah](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution can be using environment variables:
[Using environment variables for .config file in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358654/using-environment-variables-for-config-file-in-net)

Then bootstrap the application to change the app.config at runtime
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12589/Modifying-Configuration-Settings-at-Runtime